# Accessing localhost server of PC connected Android mobile device

Tags: android

i'm running my android application in my device ...
I need to access localhost server from my phone , to do that i typed my pc ip address in my phone browser and for sure i turned the server on , but it didn' work with 
Can someone help me throw this

Comment: Your phone itself is its own localhost. Every device is a localhost. Its own. Where are you talking about. Better dont use the word localhost.

Comment: Which network did you use to access the server? Your LAN?

Answer (score 0):

First thing do you use port number with your localhost if yes, then use the same port number with IP address too
e.g localhost:8080 then 172.167.172.23:8080

=======================================================

If above is not your case then try following
1) Find httpd.conf file 
  add "ALLOW FROM ALL".

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/www/">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
# Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important. Please see
# [httpd.apache.org]
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
# Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride all

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#

# onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow

Allow from ALL

</Directory>
```